# JS – Ternary operator to avoid excessive chaining in a conditional. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, code-duplication, method-chaining

```
condition ?
    domElement.classList.add('show') :
    domElement.classList.remove('show');
```

The above code works, but the DOM-variable and classList are explicitly typed twice. Is there any way to use a ternary to only put the differentiating parts of the chain in their respective true/false clause?

I'm thinking something like:

```
domElement.classList condition ? .add('show') : .remove('show');
```

Any and all input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `domElement.classList[condition ? 'add' : 'remove']('show');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
domElement.classList[condition ? 'add' : 'remove']('show')
```

Better though:

```
domElement.classList.toggle('show', condition)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods.